# Yii2: Error Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Im trying to display images from backend of my app

```
<?php foreach ($img as $key=>$row): ?>
<div class="products_inside_wrapper intro_wrapper">
<div class="classes_inside_item bordered_wht_border">
<?php
foreach (explode(';',rtrim($row['images'],';')) as $key_img => $value_img)
{
?>
<?php echo  Html::img('@backend/web'.'/'.$value_img);?>                  
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Tried with above code to display all images, but getting error `Not allowed to load local resource` when I open Google Chrome Inspect Element

Comment: Can you provide the output html ?i believe  that could give us more insight !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stig-js answered you can't load local saved image directly, If you're really interested into loading resources from a local path, you can open image as a binary file with `fopen` and echo the content of it with a proper header to output. In general way, you can add a method to your model like this:

```
public function getImage($imageName)
{
    $imagePath = '@backend/web' . '/' . $imageName;

    $fileInfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $contentType = finfo_file($fileInfo, $imagePath);
    finfo_close($fileInfo);

    $fp = fopen($imagePath, 'r');

    header("Content-Type: " . $contentType);
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($imagePath));

    ob_end_clean();
    fpassthru($fp);
}
```

P.S: Also you can use combination of this answer with showing image as base64 on HTML. See [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

i think you are using a local url instead of using this

```
<?php echo  Html::img('@backend/web'.'/'.$value_img);?>
```

try using it like

```
  <?= Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/images/'.$value_img]);?>
```

Comment: by using @web it will get files from frontend web folder I need to use files from backend web folders to frontend of my app

Comment: can u try a custom alias in the common config

Yii::setAlias('@res', 'http://example.com/backend/web/images/'); 

an in the view use like 

<?= Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@res').'/images/'.$value_img]);?>

Answer (score 1):

Images must be accesible by an url, like

```
yoursite.com/backend/imagedir/IMG'
```

If *yoursite.com/backend* points to your `backend/web` folder.

Backend alias points to your **local path**, so you need a custom alias to reach image folders.

**Yii2 aliases**: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html